# Can you explain how is moveUp() is working?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am a newbie. When I have exercise about creat Class interface Moveable, MoveablePoint.

[image]

I have searched this code on the internet but I can't understand why is moveUp() is y=y-yspeed. Can you explain to me what is yspeed (it's velocity or vector) and why y=y-yspeed.I really appreciate your answer

```
 public class MovablePoint implements Movable{

    public int x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed;

    public MovablePoint(int x, int y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    }


    @Override
    public void moveUp() {
        y -= ySpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveDown() {
        y += ySpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveRight() {
        x += xSpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveLeft() {
        x -= xSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but: If you're wondering why it's - speed instead of + speed, that's because computer coordinate systems work differently than the ones in math. The higher the y value, the lower down the point is. The top left corner, for example, is (0, 0), while the bottom right would be, for example, (1920, 1080).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you explain to me what is yspeed (it's velocity or vector)

Speed is simply "the rate at which something moves". Like you car's speed when you drive might be 35mph or 60kph, for example. It means the car covers a distance of 35 miles every hour.

It is related to but not the same as velocity (google it).

In your example, "yspeed" would seem to be the rate at which the value of the `MoveablePoint`'s y property changes.

> and why y=y-yspeed.I really appreciate your answer

Again, since speed is the rate at which something moves, that means `y` is going to move `yspeed` units over some time interval, which means it needs to be adjusted by `yspeed` amount across that time interval. Again, considering a car that starts at mile marker 0 and moves at a speed of 35mph, it will hit mile marker 35 after 1 hour. In other words, it's location `y` will be it's original position + the speed at which it moved (`y + mph`).

In this case it's *negative* (`y - yspeed`) because in screen coordinates moving "up" actually means decreasing the y position since the screen coordinates start at the top left. When y = 0 you're at the top of the screen and when you increase y you're moving down the screen.